# Time Based Graph Data Modeling

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have a data modeling question. The data that I have is basically nodes with relations to other nodes. Nodes have properties. Edges are directional and have properties. I am exploring if a Graph DB like Neo4j will be appropriate or not.

The doubt is because: The data that I have is time based. It changes on the basis of time, and I need to keep track of the historical data as well. For example, I should be able to query:

1. What was the graph like on a particular date?
2. Who all did a given node depend on at a particular time?
3. What were the properties of the edge between two given nodes at a particular time?

I searched but couldn't find a satisfactory resource where I could understand how time can be factored into a Graph DB. Do you think my requirement can be inherently met using a Graph DB? Is there an example/resource/article which describes this for Neo4j or any other graph db?

I want to make sure that the database is scalable to about 100K nodes, and millions of edges. I am optimizing for time over space.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there an example/resource/article which describes this for Neo4j or
>   any other graph db?

[Here is](http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/) an excellent article from Ian Robinson blog about time-based versioned graphs.

Basically the article describes a way to represent a time-based versioned graphs adding some extra nodes and timestamped relationships to represent the state of the graph in a given timestamp.

The following image from the referenced article shows:

1. The price of `produc_id : 1` has changed from 1.00 to 2.00. This is a state change.
2. The `product_id : 1` is now sold by `shop_id : 2` (and not by `shop_id : 1`). This is a structural change.

[image: Time based model]

> Do you think my requirement can be inherently met using a Graph DB?

Yes, but not in an easy or "natural" way. Versioning a time based model with a database that don't offers this functionality natively can be hard and expensive. From the article:

> Neo4j doesn’t provide intrinsic support either at the level of its
>   labelled property graph model or in its Cypher query language for
>   versioning. Therefore, to version a graph we need to make our
>   application graph data model and queries version aware.

and

> versioning necessarily creates a lot more data – both more nodes and
>   more relationships. In addition, queries will tend to be more complex,
>   and slower, because every MATCH must take account of one or more
>   versioned elements. Given these overheads, apply versioning with care.
>   Perhaps not all of your graph needs to be versioned. If that’s the
>   case, version only those portions of the graph that require it.

**EDIT:**

A few words from the book Graph Databases (by Ian Robinson, Jim Webber and Emil Eifrem) about versioning in graph databases. This book is [available for download at Neo4J page](https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/):

> **Versioning:**
>   A versioned graph enables us to recover the state of the
>   graph at a particular point in time. Most graph databases don’t
>   support versioning as a first-class concept. It is possible, however,
>   to create a versioning scheme inside the graph model. With this scheme
>   nodes and relationships are timestamped and archived whenever they are
>   modified The downside of such versioning schemes is that they leak
>   into any queries written against the graph, adding a layer of
>   complexity to even the simplest query.

This paragraph links the article indicated in the beginning of this answer.

Comment: Sadly the link to Ian Robinson's article is dead.

Comment: @BenjaminR thanfully there is a webarchive: https://web.archive.org/web/20180123143004/http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/